# Include non-Facelet content in a Facelet template

Tags: jsf, facelets

Is there a way to have the content of an html file inserted into a Facelet template?  The Facelets  tag will not work since it is only for including Facelet content.

To put it another way, I am looking for the Facelets equivalent to the JSP include directive `<%@ include file="..." %>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only include mechanism in Facelets is , which doesn't allow arbitrary content to be included, only well formatted XML.  There is no equivalent to the JSP include directive in Facelets.

Answer (score 4):

I may not understand what you need, but `<ui:include>` is not restricted to facelets content, you can insert valid xhtml with it, according to [this link](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-include.html).

Consider following facelets file (test.jsp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <body>
        <f:view>
            <h:outputText value="Text outside include"/>
            <ui:include src="testinclude.html"/>
        </f:view>
    </body>
</html>
```

And following HTML file (testinclude.html):

```
<h2>Text from included page</h2>
```

It includes correctly the HTML content in the page. This also applies when using `<ui:include>` in a facelets template.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  After some experimenting, I found that including an html fragment such as this:

    foo <span>bar</span>

generates an error: "Content is not allowed in prolog."  And including fragment like this:

    <span>foo</span> <span>bar</span>

generates an error: "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."  But this does work:

    <span>foo bar</span>

So the included content *must* be well formed xml (but not necessarily valid xml).

Am I correct in assuming that <ui:include> is the only insert mechanism in Facelets?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes it is. Maybe you can try to use some other mechanisms like: 

- <jsp:include .../>, which I can't tell right now if it would work, but I doubt it.

- There is also <a4j:include ...>, but RichFaces documentation seems to imply that it has the same behavior as <ui:include> 

- An HTML "iframe", but the inclusion would be done by the client side.

- A custom JSF tag which would render the content of a file.

Answer (score 1):

This describes a solution to this: http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2010/04/facelets-and-legacy-jsp.html

The solution includes building a simple UI component that loads the JSP or Servlet content into a string and renders that via the normal response writer.

Answer (score 1):

Omnifaces's `<o:resourceInclude>` can be used to include arbitrary content directly to the response. Which means it doesn't have to be well formed xml as with `<ui:include>`. Also you can include content in `<h:head>` section of your JSF page, which is tough to achieve otherwise.

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resourceInclude